# Where is the mistake in my qualitative interpretation of the change in the width of depleted region of a PN junction under an applied polarization?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

Where is the mistake in my qualitative interpretation of the change in the width of depleted region of a PN junction under an applied polarization ?

Please note that I have really *understood with equations*, and understood the textbooks.

My main problem is that I'm able, with words to prove both what happens and the opposite to what happens, so I must do a mistake in my explanation, but I don't know where.

Indeed, in the text below, I'm able, with words, to both prove the fact of increase/decrease of the depleted region with revert/direct polarization, but also prove the opposite.

Any help is very much welcome on what is wrong in my sentences.

Here is my explanations, by considering a PN junction where P is at the left, N is at the right.

**Introduction : before applying any polarization
In the N region, the majority carriers (electrons) diffuse by the Fick law to the P region where there are a minoritory. The electrons from N region combine with holes from P region, creating an electric field that tend to prevent the electrons from N region to diffuse further.
 The minority electrons from P regions derive to the N region by the electric field that has been created by the depleted region,increasing the excess of electrons in the N region, thus increasing the diffusion of electrons from N to P region. There is an balance that occurs in the reactions.

**Polarization in reverse:

1) Description that "works with hands"
When applying a revert polarisation (+ on N region, and – on P region), the electrons minority carriers from P region goes further to the N region, thus increasing
the excess of electrons in the N region, thus increasing the phenomena of diffusion of electrons from N to P region, thus increasing the recombination of electrons of N region with holes from P region, thus increasing the width of the depleted region

2) Description that does not work with hands (but I don't know where is my mistake)
When applying a revert polarisation (+ on N region, and – on P region), the electrons majority carriers in the N region will have a force that goes in the opposite direction
to their tendency to diffuse to the P region, thus they will diffuse *less* to the left, thus they will less recombine with holes, thus the depleted region width will be lower.

**Polarization in direct

3) Explanation that works with hands
When applying a direct polarisation (+ on P region, and – on N region), the electrons minority carriers from P region will go much less in the right direction, due to the positive potential at their left, thus the excess of electrons in the N region will be lower, thus the diffusion of electron from the right N region to the left P region will be lower, thus the depleted region will be lower.

4) Explanation that does not work with hands (but I don't know where is my mistake)
When applying a direct polarisation (+ on P region, and – on N region), the electons majority carriers, in addition to their tendency to diffuse, will receive a contribution of external electric field that makes them go in a higher rate to the left region, thus allowing to combine with holes in the P region at a further distance, thus increasing the depleted region with respect to the case of the absence of a polarization.

Comment: perhaps using equation might help you find why the wording is wrong.

Comment: Electrons are majority carriers in the n-type region. Holes are the majority carriers in the p-type region. In the depletion region electrons and holes recombine. For semiconductors you MUST treat holes on an equal footing with electrons to get a clear picture of carrier densities and behavior.

Comment: @Jon Custer Thank you. I know all that. But still, as you see, I'm able to make a paragraph that could state that the behaviour is the opposite to what it is. If you would know where is my mistake, I would appreciate.